# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 + unixODBC 2.3.1 + Informix clientsdk 4.10 + node.js v0.10.20

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-12.04, informix, unixodbc

I'd learn a lot readings yours questions and answers.

But now i am lost

As you can see on title, i play with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 + unixODBC 2.3.1 + Informix clientsdk 4.10 + node.js v0.10.20....

Every things is right until i try to connect in the node.js environment with unixODBC and the Informix Driver.

I have no problem with SQLServer. So node is ok, unixODBC is ok and SQLServer Driver too. 
And the Informix Driver looks like is right too, but.

I can $ isql -v MYDSN and query database.

But when the node App try to connect crash.

The DSN is realy easy and isql can play:

```
/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
[NIFX]
Driver=/opt/IBM/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
Server=explotacion
LogonID=informix
pwd=enterpass
Database=data
```

and playing width isql looks well

```
$ isql  NIFX
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PACIENTES   
+------------------+
|                  |
+------------------+
| 414396           |
+------------------+
SQLRowCount returns -1
1 rows fetched
SQL>
```

My testifx.js for node  looks

```
var Database = require("odbc").Database,
    db = new Database(),
    cn="DSN=NIFX"

db.open(cn, function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  db.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PACIENTES', [], function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    console.log(data);

    db.close(function () {
      console.log('done');
    });
  });
});
```

And the result...

```
$ node testifx
{ error: '[node-odbc] SQL_ERROR',
  message: '[unixODBC][',
  state: '0' }
$
```

Can any one help me with this.

What's wrong width odbc.ini or maybe put some other parametrers in the connection string (I've tray all found out there in the google space)

Thanks really much.

---

Thanks Michael
Sorry for the long log.

I've done what you say.
First log trace to file settings the appropriate environment in odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC]
TraceFile = /home/srlopez/Dev/unixODBC.log
Trace = Yes
```

Second, run **isql -v NIFX**, and play a single command **SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FSIGBLO**.
I just direct the DSN by name.

Done right and the trace is:

```
[ODBC][7151][1380810414.400667][__handles.c][460]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Environment = 0x63c750
[ODBC][7151][1380810414.400743][SQLAllocHandle.c][375]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0x63c750
[ODBC][7151][1380810414.400773][SQLAllocHandle.c][493]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Output Handle = 0x63d070
[ODBC][7151][1380810414.400803][SQLConnect.c][3700]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x63d070
            Server Name = [NIFX][length = 4 (SQL_NTS)]
            User Name = [NULL]
            Authentication = [NULL]
        UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'UTF8' and UNICODE 'UTF16LE'

[ODBC][7151][1380810414.803879][SQLConnect.c][4273]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7151][1380810414.810623][SQLGetFunctions.c][151]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x63d070
            Id = SQLMoreResults
            Supported = 0x6061d8
[ODBC][7151][1380810414.810759][SQLGetFunctions.c][186]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Supported = 0x6061d8 -> 1
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.644512][SQLAllocHandle.c][540]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 3
            Input Handle = 0x63d070
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.644621][SQLAllocHandle.c][1081]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Output Handle = 0x6b7aa0
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.644661][SQLPrepare.c][196]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
            SQL = [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FSIGBLO ][length = 29]
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.646046][SQLPrepare.c][371]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.646087][SQLExecute.c][187]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.646913][SQLExecute.c][348]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.646949][SQLNumResultCols.c][156]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
            Column Count = 0x7fffc7b20e8e
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.646984][SQLNumResultCols.c][248]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Count = 0x7fffc7b20e8e -> 1
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.647030][SQLNumResultCols.c][156]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
            Column Count = 0x7fffc7b20bae
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.647057][SQLNumResultCols.c][248]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Count = 0x7fffc7b20bae -> 1
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.647090][SQLColAttribute.c][293]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
            Column Number = 1
            Field Identifier = SQL_DESC_DISPLAY_SIZE
            Character Attr = (nil)
            Buffer Length = 0
            String Length = (nil)
            Numeric Attribute = 0x7fffc7b20a08
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.647129][SQLColAttribute.c][664]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.647156][SQLColAttribute.c][293]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
            Column Number = 1
            Field Identifier = SQL_DESC_LABEL
            Character Attr = 0x7fffc7b20a10
            Buffer Length = 301
            String Length = (nil)
            Numeric Attribute = (nil)
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.647192][SQLColAttribute.c][664]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.647218][SQLColAttribute.c][293]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
            Column Number = 1
            Field Identifier = SQL_DESC_LABEL
            Character Attr = 0x7fffc7b20cf0
            Buffer Length = 301
            String Length = (nil)
            Numeric Attribute = (nil)
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.647244][SQLColAttribute.c][664]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.647295][SQLNumResultCols.c][156]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
            Column Count = 0x7fffc7b20bbe
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.647322][SQLNumResultCols.c][248]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Count = 0x7fffc7b20bbe -> 1
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.647347][SQLFetch.c][162]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.648100][SQLFetch.c][348]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.648137][SQLColAttribute.c][293]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
            Column Number = 1
            Field Identifier = SQL_DESC_DISPLAY_SIZE
            Character Attr = (nil)
            Buffer Length = 0
            String Length = (nil)
            Numeric Attribute = 0x7fffc7b20a28
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.648164][SQLColAttribute.c][664]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.648189][SQLColAttribute.c][293]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
            Column Number = 1
            Field Identifier = SQL_DESC_LABEL
            Character Attr = 0x7fffc7b20a30
            Buffer Length = 301
            String Length = (nil)
            Numeric Attribute = (nil)
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.648218][SQLColAttribute.c][664]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.648254][SQLGetData.c][237]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
            Column Number = 1
            Target Type = 1 SQL_CHAR
            Buffer Length = 301
            Target Value = 0x7fffc7b20d00
            StrLen Or Ind = 0x7fffc7b20bb0
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.648358][SQLGetData.c][501]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]                
            Buffer = [2]                
            Strlen Or Ind = 0x7fffc7b20bb0 -> 1
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.648453][SQLFetch.c][162]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.648485][SQLFetch.c][348]
        Exit:[SQL_NO_DATA]
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.677380][SQLRowCount.c][173]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
            Row Count = 0x7fffc7b20e48
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.677455][SQLRowCount.c][244]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Row Count = 0x7fffc7b20e48 -> -1
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.677539][SQLMoreResults.c][162]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.678583][SQLMoreResults.c][317]
        Exit:[SQL_NO_DATA]
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.678630][SQLFreeStmt.c][144]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x6b7aa0
            Option = 1
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.678661][SQLFreeHandle.c][381]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 3
            Input Handle = 0x6b7aa0
[ODBC][7151][1380810428.679476][SQLFreeHandle.c][491]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7151][1380810430.715614][SQLDisconnect.c][208]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x63d070
[ODBC][7151][1380810430.719032][SQLDisconnect.c][364]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7151][1380810430.719070][SQLFreeHandle.c][284]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0x63d070
[ODBC][7151][1380810430.719093][SQLFreeHandle.c][333]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7151][1380810430.719116][SQLFreeHandle.c][219]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 1
            Input Handle = 0x63c750
```

Then run node test.js, with this Connection string cn='NIFX'
to pass the same information on odbc.ini to both environments isql and node.
and the trace is

```
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.770556][__handles.c][460]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Environment = 0x1438f10
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.770647][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][189]
        Entry:
            Environment = 0x1438f10
            Attribute = SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION
            Value = 0x3
            StrLen = -5
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.770677][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][363]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.781819][SQLAllocHandle.c][375]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0x1438f10
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.782068][SQLAllocHandle.c][493]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Output Handle = 0x7fc6000008c0
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.782802][SQLSetConnectAttrW.c][332]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x7fc6000008c0
            Attribute = SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMEOUT
            Value = 0x7fc607ffee4c
            StrLen = 4
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.782922][SQLSetConnectAttrW.c][616]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.782968][SQLDriverConnectW.c][290]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x7fc6000008c0
            Window Hdl = (nil)
            Str In = [DSN=NIFX][length = 9]
            Str Out = (nil)
            Str Out Max = 0
            Str Out Ptr = (nil)
            Completion = 0
        UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'UTF8' and UNICODE 'UTF16LE'

**[ODBC][7171][1380810558.787449][SQLDriverConnectW.c][699]
        Exit:[SQL_ERROR]**
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.787689][SQLGetDiagFieldW.c][792]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x7fc6000008c0
            Rec Number = 1
            Diag Ident = 2
            Diag Info Ptr = 0x7fffdc53aca8
            Buffer Length = -6
            String Len Ptr = 0x7fffdc53acae
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.787802][SQLGetDiagFieldW.c][812]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.787839][SQLGetDiagRecW.c][508]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x7fc6000008c0
            Rec Number = 1
            SQLState = 0x7fffdc53aeb0
            Native = 0x7fffdc53aca4
            Message Text = 0x7fffdc53acb0
            Buffer Length = 512
            Text Len Ptr = 0x7fffdc53acae
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.787873][SQLGetDiagRecW.c][550]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            SQLState = H
            Native = 0x7fffdc53aca4 -> -11060
            Message Text = [[unixODBC][]
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.788053][SQLGetDiagRecW.c][508]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x7fc6000008c0
            Rec Number = 2
            SQLState = 0x7fffdc53aeb0
            Native = 0x7fffdc53aca4
            Message Text = 0x7fffdc53acb0
            Buffer Length = 512
            Text Len Ptr = 0x7fffdc53acae
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.788174][SQLGetDiagRecW.c][550]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            SQLState = 0
            Native = 0x7fffdc53aca4 -> -11005
            Message Text = [[unixODBC][]
```

And these are my conclusion.
node playing with unixODBC call differents functions.
**isql** call **SQLConnect.c** and **node** call **SQLDriverConnectW.c**, like this:

**NODE** just functions calls until Connect

```
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.770556][__handles.c][460]
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.770647][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][189]
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.770677][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][363]
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.781819][SQLAllocHandle.c][375]
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.782068][SQLAllocHandle.c][493]
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.782802][SQLSetConnectAttrW.c][332]
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.782922][SQLSetConnectAttrW.c][616]
[ODBC][7171][1380810558.782968][SQLDriverConnectW.c][290]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x7fc6000008c0
            Window Hdl = (nil)
            Str In = [DSN=NIFX][length = 9]
            Str Out = (nil)
            Str Out Max = 0
            Str Out Ptr = (nil)
            Completion = 0
        UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'UTF8' and UNICODE 'UTF16LE'

[ODBC][7171][1380810558.787449][SQLDriverConnectW.c][699]
        Exit:[SQL_ERROR]
```

**isql** just functions calls until Connect

```
[ODBC][7151][1380810414.400667][__handles.c][460]
[ODBC][7151][1380810414.400743][SQLAllocHandle.c][375]
[ODBC][7151][1380810414.400773][SQLAllocHandle.c][493]
[ODBC][7151][1380810414.400803][SQLConnect.c][3700]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x63d070
            Server Name = [NIFX][length = 4 (SQL_NTS)]
            User Name = [NULL]
            Authentication = [NULL]
        UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'UTF8' and UNICODE 'UTF16LE'

**[ODBC][7151][1380810414.803879][SQLConnect.c][4273]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]**
```

How to address this question?
Thanks in advance again.

Santi

Comment: The error occur at what line? when execute the SELECT or when go to open the connection? The error message is incomplete, check if there is no way to get more details about the error.

Comment: In traces it is strange that connect string from `isql`: `NIFX` is 4 characters long, where connect string from `node.js`: `DSN=NIFX` is 9 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable ODBC call tracing. At first run `isql` to obtain log of valid calls. Then do the same for `node.js`. Comparing them should show you where is the problem.

There is my question and answer on how to enable ODBC tracing for Informix on Linux : [Tracing ODBC calls for Informix Client for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657994/tracing-odbc-calls-for-informix-client-for-linux)

**EDIT:**

From logs it seems that `node.js` uses `SQLDriverConnectW()` which ends with error: -11005. Informix show error describe this as *"Invalid connection string attribute."*.

You can use the same connect string as `isql`:

```
cn="NIFX"
```

If it do not work than maybe you should add user/password:

```
cn="Dsn=NIFX;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"
```

In Python I often use it in form:

```
dsn/user/password
```

You can also try to add to connect string more info just like it is shown on: http://www.connectionstrings.com/informix

Comment: Thanks Michal.
I've done what you said. And the trace is added to the question.

Comment: Try to add more attributes: at leas username and password to your connect string